# How to resize and rename an image at the time that I am uploading it?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to resize (to create a valid thumbnail) and rename a file when I am uploading it in a view in Django. I saw library PIL and I am using it but with no results.

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.urls import reverse
from PIL import Image

@login_required
def zoom(request):
    uploaded_url = {}
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.getlist('document', False):
        myfiles = request.FILES.getlist('document')
        for myfile in myfiles:
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
            uploaded_url[filename] = uploaded_file_url
            imagen = ((Image.open(myfile)).resize((191,176))).save("thumb.png")
    return render(request, "visores/acercamiento.html", {
        'uploaded_url' : uploaded_url,
    })
```

acercamiento.html

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h4>Búsqueda general</h4>
    <input type="file" name="document" accept="image/*" id="b">
    <button type="submit" id="subir">Subir imagen</button>
</form>
{% if uploaded_url %}
    {% for name, url in uploaded_url.items %}
        {% load static %}
        <div id="bai">
            <a class="magnifier-thumb-wrapper demo" href="{{ url }}"> 
            <img id="thumb2" src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/thumb.png'>
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Expected results:
/media/P1565.png
/media/thumb.png

Actual result:
/media/P1565.png

Comment: You should do that in you form or on your model, not in the view.

Comment: I am doing it in this way because I have limitations of space and I don't need models in this little app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! Thanks to @Viktor Petrov, this is part of the code in view that saves the file in carpet "media":

```py
thumb_url = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(uploaded_file_url), 'thumb.png')  # specify your thumbnail URL;
imagen = (Image.open(myfile)).resize((191,176),Image.ANTIALIAS).save(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT,'thumb.png')) # re-size and save your thumbnail to the corresponding path;            
uploaded_url['thumb.png'] = thumb_url
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not returning the URL of your newly saved thumbnail to your template.

```
filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)  # you're saving "P1565.png";
uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)  # you're getting the URL for "P1565.png";
uploaded_url[filename] = uploaded_file_url  # the URL value is "/media/P1565.png";
```

So you should set the uploaded_url value to your thumb.png URL after you re-size and save it.

```
thumb_url = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(uploaded_file_url), 'thumb.png')  # specify your thumbnail URL;
imagen = ((Image.open(myfile)).resize((191,176))).save('thumb.png')  # re-size and save your thumbnail to the corresponding path;
uploaded_url[filename] = thumb_url  # assign the new URL as the new value;
```

Comment: @Victor, it's ok, thanks, the file is saved, but location is up in the root carpet. This way: "/media/P1565.png" and "/thumb.png". I think that this line `imagen = ((Image.open(myfile)).resize((191,176))).save('thumb.png')` is making that it is saved in "/" which is inaccessible

Comment: Right, yeah, I assumed you were saving it in the media root. Please consider upvoting my answer if it helped you.